# How to reuse functions in Next.js with TypeScript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js

apparently, it is considered a best practice if you can split all the data fetching functions to a separate folder called `services` and put all the functions there then use them in the project
However, I couldn't make it happen with Next.js
The function works when I put it inside the same component I want to render the data inside it, but doesn't work when I put the function in a separate folder and export it.
I get this error:

```
 TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')
```

I think it is because the data props are not being passed to the component correctly.

below are the working and none working examples :

**the Working example:**

inside `index.tsx` file  :

```
export async function getStaticProps() {
  const response = await fetch(
    `https://api.github.com/users/abdurrahmanseyidoglu/repos`
  );
  const data = await response.json();

  if (!data) {
    return {
      notFound: true,
    };
  }

  return {
    props: {
      data,
    }, // will be passed to the page component as props
  };
}

const Home = ({ data }) => {
  return (
    <>
      <ul>
        {data.map((repo) => (
          <li key={repo.id}>{repo.name}</li>
        ))}
      </ul>
      <p className="max-w-5xl m-auto text-justify mt-2 border rounded p-3 shadow-lg">
       Working Example
      </p>
    </>
  );
};

export default Home;
```

**Not Working example:**

inside `services/getUserRepos.ts` :

```
export async function getStaticProps() {
  const response = await fetch(
    `https://api.github.com/users/abdurrahmanseyidoglu/repos`
  );
  const data = await response.json();

  if (!data) {
    return {
      notFound: true,
    };
  }

  return {
    props: {
      data,
    }, 
  };
}
```

inside `index.tsx` file :

```
import { getStaticProps } from "../services/getUserRepos";
const Home = ({ data }) => {
  return (
    <>
      <ul>
        {data.map((repo) => (
          <li key={repo.id}>{repo.name}</li>
        ))}
      </ul>
      <p className="max-w-5xl m-auto text-justify mt-2 border rounded p-3 shadow-lg">
       None Working Example
      </p>
    </>
  );
};

export default Home;
```

How can I make it so I can pass the fetched data from a separate folder to my `index.tsx` file

Comment: `getStaticProps` need to be exported from the page file. You import it and don't do anything with it. So `index.tsx` has no exported function `getStaticProps` and therefore doesn't work. https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching/get-static-props

Comment: You can declare the inner logic of the `getStaticProps` function into a separate function/file, for reusability. Import the function and use is within the `getStaticProps` function, which you then export.

Comment: @W.S. I'm getting this error ```Error: Error serializing `.data` returned from `getStaticProps` in "/".
Reason: `undefined` cannot be serialized as JSON. Please use `null` or omit this value.```

Comment: @W.S. if you can provide a working solution I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

inside `services/user.service.ts` :

```
export async function getUserRepos() {
  const response = await fetch(
    `https://api.github.com/users/abdurrahmanseyidoglu/repos`
  );
  const data = await response.json();
  return data;
}
```

inside `index.tsx` file :

```js
import { getUserRepos } from "../services/user.service";

export async function getStaticProps() {
  const data = await getUserRepos();

  if (!data) {
    return {
      notFound: true,
    };
  }

  return {
    props: {
      data,
    }, // will be passed to the page component as props
  };
}

const Home = ({ data }) => {
  return (
    <>
      <ul>
        {data.map((repo) => (
          <li key={repo.id}>{repo.name}</li>
        ))}
      </ul>
      <p className="max-w-5xl m-auto text-justify mt-2 border rounded p-3 shadow-lg">
       Working Example
      </p>
    </>
  );
};

export default Home;
```

Comment: Thank you!, now I understand how to use a function from another file/folder with SSG support

Answer (score 1):

You are not using `getStaticProps` after importing it, your code should look like this

```js
import {getStaticProps} from "../services/getUserRepos";
import {useState} from "react";

const Home = () => {
    const [userRepos, setUserRepos] = useState([]);

    getStaticProps().then((data) => setUserRepos(data));

    return (
        <>
            <ul>
                {userRepos.map((repo) => (
                    <li key={repo.id}>{repo.name}</li>
                ))}
            </ul>
            <p className="max-w-5xl m-auto text-justify mt-2 border rounded p-3 shadow-lg">
                None Working Example
            </p>
        </>
    );
};

export default Home;
```

Comment: I'm getting this error : ```Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: [object Promise]). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.```

Comment: if you can provide a fully working solution I would appreciate it.

Comment: @MrXQ Yep, my bad i didn't catch that fully, i've edited the message and fixed it.

Comment: Thank you, It is working now,


Do you know How can I achieve it using the```getStaticProps``` function for SSG? 
Like what ```W.S``` said in his comment

Comment: Im not too sure about that, but i believe that when u build the production it will automatically put static pages in the build folder. But again i've never tried it so im not sure on how it works.