# How to reuse functions service in Next.js

Tags: typescript, next.js

I'm new to Next.js and I like to split my API function to a separate folder called `services`.
I have try to make some code based to this [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72980185/how-to-reuse-functions-in-next-js-with-typescript) but it's didn't work. I think my api function is never call. I get this error:

```
Unhandled Runtime Error
TypeError: data is undefined
```

This is my code

`index.tsx` file :

```
import ShowResult from '../components/showResult'

export default function Home() {
  return (
    <div className='container mx-auto'>      
      <ShowResult />
    </div>
  );
}
```

`components/showResult.tsx` file :

```
import getUserRepos from '../services/api.service'

export async function getStaticProps() {
  const data = await getUserRepos();

  if (!data) {
    return {
      notFound: true,
    };
  }

  return {
    props: {
      data,
    },
  };
}

export default function ShowResult({data}) {
  return (
    <div className=''>
      <p>Result :</p>
      <ul>
        {data.map((repo) => (
          <li key={repo.id}>{repo.name}</li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </div>
  )
}
```

`services/api.service.ts` file :

```
export async function getUserRepos() {
  const response = await fetch(
    `https://api.github.com/users/abdurrahmanseyidoglu/repos`
  );
  const data = await response.json();
  return data;
}
```

How can a get the data from my api service function ?

Comment: I find a solution. I have mouve my `components` and my `services` folders out of my `app` folder. I put them on the same level than `app`, now I got this folders structure : `app, components, node_modules, public, services, package.json, ...`

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to Move `getStaticProps` to your page and then pass the data to ShowResult component as a prop.
Then change your `ShowResult` component to accept the data as a prop and render it.

Try this:

pages/index.tsx:

```
import ShowResult from '../components/ShowResult';
import { getUserRepos } from '../services/api.service';

export async function getStaticProps() {
  const data = await getUserRepos();

  if (!data) {
    return {
      notFound: true,
    };
  }

  return {
    props: {
      data,
    },
  };
}

export default function Home({ data }) {
  return (
    <div className='container mx-auto'>      
      <ShowResult data={data} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

components/ShowResult.tsx:

```
export default function ShowResult({ data }) {
  if (!data) {
    return <div>No data to display.</div>;
  }

  return (
    <div className=''>
      <p>Result:</p>
      <ul>
        {data.map((repo) => (
          <li key={repo.id}>{repo.name}</li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}
```

services/api.service.ts (unchanged):

```
export async function getUserRepos() {
  const response = await fetch(
    `https://api.github.com/users/abdurrahmanseyidoglu/repos`
  );
  if (!response.ok) {
    throw new Error(`Failed to fetch repos, received status ${response.status}`);
  }
  const data = await response.json();
  return data;
}
```

Comment: Thank for your answer. I have make the changes but I got a new error : `"getStaticProps" is not supported in app/. Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/data-fetching`

Comment: I find a solution. I have mouve my `components` and my `services` folders out of my `app` folder. I put them on the same level than `app`, now I got this folders structure : `app, components, node_modules, public, services, package.json, ...`